# Change HTML downloadlink into downloadbutton through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to create a function where I can generate a blob .json file, which I then want to download.

I've checked around and found one way to do it.

```
function download_rapport(){
    var data = geojson.features.map(function(row) { return row.properties; });
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    var blob = new Blob([json], {type: "application/json"});
    var url  = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download    = "backup.json";
    a.href        = url;
    a.textContent = "Download backup.json";

    document.getElementById('content_test').innerHTML = a.outerHTML;
    // 'çontent_test' is a <div>
};
```

This works pretty well, however, this method uses a link to download. I would prefer to use a button, because it fits better with the rest of my application.

I used multiple methods to try and get a download button, but I always end up with a button that sends me to a new page with the data that I need shown as a string.

Is there a way to change my function so that it generates a downloadbutton instead of a downloadlink?

**EDIT:**

I've edited my code a bit with help from Midas. However, when I alter the data in my `var json` and try to download the "new" file, it will always download the "first" `var json`.

What I would like, is to be able to alter the `var json` data, and always download the "latest" version of it.

```
window.onload = function testreer() {
    var data = geojson.features.map(function(row) { return row.properties; });
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    var blob = new Blob([json], {type: "application/json"});
    var url  = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var b = document.createElement('button');

    a.download = blob;
    a.href = url;
    b.innerText = 'Download';

    document.getElementById('content_test').appendChild(b);
    b.appendChild(a);

    b.addEventListener('click', function() {
        a.click();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** I have append a button in a link if that what you want.

```
function download_rapport(){
    var data = geojson.features.map(function(row) { return row.properties; });
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    var blob = new Blob([json], {type: "application/json"});
    var url  = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download    = "backup.json";
    a.href        = url;
    // 'çontent_test' is a <div>

    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.value="download";
    btn.innerHTML = "Download JSON";
    a.appendChild(btn);

    document.getElementById('content_test').innerHTML = a.outerHTML;
};
```

Comment: I've used something like this, but when I click the new button nothing happens.

Comment: @JordiZ just assign the correct `url` in `a.url`, url should be of the backup.json file. and it will prompt to download.

Comment: The correct `url` is already defined in `a.href`. When hovering over the button it sees the `url` as `blob:http://localhost/3a5ff533-08bd-4fcd-950f-70cee41912cd`, it just won't do anything. When I open the button in a new tab, I just get a new page with the data as a string.

Comment: Also, when checking the console, the <button> is place inside of the <a> tags: `<a download="backup.json" href="blob:http://localhost/fa9e7e60-da19-4f85-94b1-d98b76714590">
<button value="download">Download JSON</button>`
</a>

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it it a button if you like

replace

```
document.createElement('a');
```

with

```
document.createElement("BUTTON");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a button has no `href` attribute like an `a` tag, you have to assign the desired action to the `onclick` event on the fly. An example is as follows:

```js
window.onload = function()
{
    var url = 'http://lipsum.com';

    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.innerText = 'Download';
    document.getElementById('content_test').appendChild(btn);

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        window.location.href = url;
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="content_test"></div>
```

**Edit:**

Since the file is not coming from a server, you can create both the `a` tag and the `button` tag, triggering the link programmatically when the button is clicked:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var url = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/300/technics/';

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var b = document.createElement('button');

    a.download = 'technics.jpg';
    a.href = url;
    b.innerText = 'Download';

    document.getElementById('content_test').appendChild(b);
    b.appendChild(a);

    b.addEventListener('click', function() {
        a.click();
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="content_test"></div>
```

However, In normal circumstances you would set `Content-Disposition: attachment` on the server side, to tell the browser that the file is to be downloaded.

Comment: Using this method I go to the page specified in the link, instead of downloading the data.

Comment: @JordiZ Ok, got it. In that case you can generate both elements, a link plus the button, and trigger a click event on the link when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to give up on changing the link to a button. Instead, I will use CSS to style the  link as a button. After checking around I found out that, although it is possible to change a link to a button, it is way faster to just use CSS to style it.

I edited my code a tiny bit by adding `a.id = "downloadLink"` to give the generated `<a>` an ID. This ID is then styled in my CSS file.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download    = "backup.json";
    a.href        = url;
    a.id          = "downloadLink";
    a.textContent = "Download backup.json";
```

Comment: Sorry, was away for a couple of days. I used your code and it works fine. However, when I alter the JSON data and try to download the file, it will always download the "first" JSON file. I edited my question with my updated code.